# Log queries in ORIENTDB

Tags: logging, orientdb

I've running orientDB 1.7.9 on Windows using server.bat batch file. 
I need to see all queries executed on server. I've changed all logging settings to ALL in configuration files. But without any luck.

how should i configure logging to see executed queries in log?

Thanks.

Comment: I've made [that question](https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/3510) before but no answer.
But the query profiler in workbench (available in Enterprise edition) logs all queries.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the Query Profiler.